# Simplification of another nasty expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I have the following condition 
$$ 2 \frac{x^2}{y^2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{y^2} \right)+ \frac{1}{y^2} \leq 1$$

Can anyone help me simplify it to the best possible relationship between $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 4):

Take $1$ to the LHS and factor. This gives you
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\left(2\frac{x^2}{y^2}-1\right)\leq 0.
$$
From here, you can consider 3 cases: $y^2>1$, $y^2< 1$, and $y^2=1$.